# Visual Studio 2015 - a lot of Packages are missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

So I recently bought a new computer. And now I wanted to install visual studio 2015. So I did. But now the problem is that i cant create a new project because i cant select a vb.net form or anything else and also im getting these error messages saying:

- The 'ErrorListPackage' package did not load correctly
- The'VisualStudioPackage' package did not load correctly
- The Microsoft.visual studio package did not load correctly

anyone has a solution for this? because I'm kinda getting a bit frustrated now.
I tried a complete uninstall and install and it didnt work. I tried copying folders from my laptop to my new pc but also that didn't work. Also switching frameworks doesn't do anything. I also never experienced this problem before but can this problem occure because I have 2 drives?? Seems odd but I think I'm also going to do an uninstall again and then try the .iso installer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I fixed it for myself.
I removed all files and folders that are linked to visual studio

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
- C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services
- C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
- C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VsGraphics

After I deleted all of those folders I deleted the regkeys located:

- HKLM > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Visual Studio

After that I started the visual studio installer with admin rights.
And now I can create a project :)

Comment: Thus process may leave a lot if other stuff around, next time try 'vs_setup /uninstall /force'

Comment: NEVER delete folders (even worse : registry entries) by yourself - thats assured to break your system even more

Comment: I dont agree on the "Never delete folder" unless special folders. but yes just be careful when deleting reg-keys.

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates an issue with an extension which ships with some dependent assemblies which Visual Studio itself (or another extension) also depends on. When these dependencies are different versions, it's not predictable which version will load.

To solve your problem, first disable your extensions and add-ins, then close Visual Studio, clear the ComponentModelCache folder under:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```

And start Visual Studio again.

This should clear the immediate issue.

Now enable each extension one-by-one restarting Visual Studio every time to see if the issues come back.

To dive deeper into the underlying issue, you could look into all the extensions under these folders:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions
```

Look for assemblies from Microsoft itself (commonly found are `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.` in folders containing an extension that did not originate from Microsoft. These extensions are common culprits for these issues.

If you want to dig deeper, consider using `fuslogvw` from the Windows SDK to see which assemblies are loaded and which exact versions they are. You can also look into the Visual Studio logs after the issue surfaces to see what underlying cause there may be. The log should be available under:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.XML
```

Comment: I have tried all of that and it didn't work. But i have fixed it myself :)

Comment: Please share your solution then :)